# Google Cloud Registry and multiple projects

Tags: docker, gcp

Is it possible to pull images from the same `GCR` from multiple `GCP` projects without making the registry public?

I want to do this so I do not have to upload multiple times the same image to multiple registries so it can be used on different projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Fundamentally GCR is built on top of Cloud Storage, with roughly the same basic access control:

- public, i.e completely accessible
- private, with quite flexible access control from pretty much anywhere, even from outside the GCP domain - being in a certain GCP project is rather irrelevant.

From [Granting users and other projects access to a registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control#granting_users_and_other_projects_access_to_a_registry):

> To give specific users or container clusters running on other projects
>   permissions to pull images from a registry, you need to grant read
>   permission on the underlying Cloud Storage bucket.
>
> ...
>
> 4. Select the **Permissions** tab.
> 5. Click **Add members**.
> 6. From the menu that appears, fill the **Members** field with the email addresses of users needing read permission, separated by commas.
>      This email address can be one of the following:
>
>    - a Google account (for example, `someone@example.com`)
>    - a Cloud IAM service account
>    - the [Compute Engine default service account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#compute_engine_default_service_account) of another project. This account is used by the Google Kubernetes Engine to pull
>        container images clusters by default. It is in the form
>        `[PROJECT_NUMBER]-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`, where
>        `[PROJECT-NUMBER]` is the [GCP project number](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#identifying_projects) of the project that
>        is running the Google Kubernetes Engine cluster.

There are some differences from Cloud Storage, most notable ones being:

- access control applies to the bucket level only, object level access is ignored
- GCR can only have a single bucket per GCP project